# How to create javascript objects in an existing object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm fairly new to javascript and I just started learning about objects & arrays. I have an object like this:

```
var myObj= {'1'{ID:'1',x:200,y:300},
              '2'{ID:'2',x:100,y:100}};
```

I'm willing to create another object inside the existing object("myObj") so that I can access it's properties using `myObj['key'].x`.
Assume that I want to add the object `{ID:'3',x:100,y:200}` into myObj and access it's property values using `myObj[3].x`, `myObj[3].y` etc., I know that `.push` only works for arrays so I'm out of options.

Comment: `myObj['key'] = {x:200};` - doesn't that do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunc(id, x, y){
    var obj={};
    obj.ID = id.toString();
    obj.x = x;
    obj.y = y;
    return obj;
}
function myFunc2(id, x, y){
    myObj[id] = myFunc(id, x, y);
}
```

You can use `myObj[3].x`to get the "x" value from the object.

Edited: Call myFunc2 with desired parameters. e.g., `myFunc2(3,100,200);`

Comment: The implicit reference to `myObj` inside the function is a rather ugly construct; why don't you simply return the new object so that you can do `myObj[3] = myFunc(105, 100, 200);`?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to javascript, too. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `myObj[3] = {ID:'3',x:100,y:200};` to add the object.